# Return cursor in function in db2

Tags: function, db2

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PPP ()
       RETURNS cursor 
  F1: BEGIN ATOMIC
          declare c1 cursor ;

          set c1 = CURSOR FOR select * from aaa ; {get error here}

          RETURN c1 ;
  END
```

My error is

A.PPP - Deploy started.
Create user-defined function returns SQLCODE: -104, SQLSTATE: 42601.
A.PPP: 6: An unexpected token "FOR" was found following "
set c1 = CURSOR".  Expected tokens may include:  "<compound_SQL_stmts1>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56
An unexpected token "FOR" was found following "
set c1 = CURSOR".  Expected tokens may include:  "<compound_SQL_stmts1>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.19.56
A.PPP - Deploy failed.
A.PPP - Roll back completed successfully.

If i wrire `set c1 = ...` in Stored Procedure, i don't get error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get this error because your syntax is not valid.

One of the many restrictions on inline SQL blocks (that is, any compound block that starts with`BEGIN ATOMIC` ), is that:

> "Cursors and condition handlers are not supported in inline SQL PL and
> therefore neither is the RESIGNAL statement."

See [docs](http://Cursors%20and%20condition%20handlers%20are%20not%20supported%20in%20inline%20SQL%20PL%20and%20therefore%20neither%20is%20the%20RESIGNAL%20statement.).

To get your code to compile , the function should not be inlined, but instead be a compiled block, replace `BEGIN ATOMIC` by `BEGIN`.

Compilation is just the first step, you will also need to get the function to execute correctly - other changes may be needed.